# Why is codedov not showing the report?

Tags: code-coverage, github-actions, codeception

Added a file with the following content to github actions .yml:

```yaml
name: build

on:
  push:
    branches: [ stable, development ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ stable, development ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    continue-on-error: ${{ matrix.experimental }}
    strategy:
      max-parallel: 2
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        php: [7.4, 8.0]
        experimental: [false]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Setup PHP Action
      uses: shivammathur/setup-php@2.16.0
      with:
        php-version: ${{ matrix.php }}
        coverage: xdebug

    - name: Validate composer.json and composer.lock
      run: composer validate --strict

    - name: Cache Composer packages
      id: composer-cache
      uses: actions/cache@v2
      with:
        path: vendor
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-php-${{ hashFiles('**/composer.lock') }}
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-php-
          
    - name: Install dependencies with Composer
      uses: ramsey/composer-install@v1
        
    - name: Run unit tests
      run: php vendor/bin/codecept run unit
      
    - name: Run Codecept coverage
      run: php vendor/bin/codecept run --coverage --coverage-xml --coverage-phpunit

    - name: Download artifacts
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v2

    - name: Codecov
      uses: codecov/codecov-action@v2.1.0
      with:
        token: ${{ secrets.CODECOV_TOKEN }}
        directory: ./tests/_output
        files: ./tests/_output/coverage.xml
        flags: unittests
        verbose: true
        fail_ci_if_error: true
```

At the very bottom is the action for uploading reports to codecov. I generate the report using codeception using the "**Run Codecept coverage**" command.

Why on the codecov site I see commits and 100% coverage, but on the main page of the codecov repository I see only instructions and an inscription:

> No repository activation required. Simply upload a report and the project activates automatically

Below, I attach a report:

```
Run codecov/codecov-action@v2.1.0
==> linux OS detected
https://uploader.codecov.io/latest/linux/codecov.SHA256SUM
==> SHASUM file signed by key id 806bb28aed779869
==> Uploader SHASUM verified (3f724b412751ee8362535f73c54cf93b0d008ed59f3e333c1f0c8532978da297  codecov)
==> Running version latest
==> Running version v0.1.9
/home/runner/work/_actions/codecov/codecov-action/v2.1.0/dist/codecov -n  -Q github-action-2.1.0 -Z -f ./tests/_output/coverage.xml -F unittests -s ./tests/_output -v
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.448Z] ['verbose'] Start of uploader: 1641808248448...
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.455Z] ['info'] 
     _____          _
    / ____|        | |
   | |     ___   __| | ___  ___ _____   __
   | |    / _ \ / _` |/ _ \/ __/ _ \ \ / /
   | |___| (_) | (_| |  __/ (_| (_) \ V /
    \_____\___/ \__,_|\___|\___\___/ \_/

  Codecov report uploader 0.1.13
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.461Z] ['info'] => Project root located at: /home/runner/work/php-data-entities/php-data-entities
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.461Z] ['info'] ->  Token found by environment variables
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.462Z] ['verbose'] Start of network processing...
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.462Z] ['verbose'] Searching for files in /home/runner/work/php-data-entities/php-data-entities
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.469Z] ['info'] Searching for coverage files...
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.480Z] ['verbose'] Preparing to clean the following coverage paths: ./tests/_output/coverage.xml
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.487Z] ['info'] => Found 1 possible coverage files:
  ./tests/_output/coverage.xml
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.487Z] ['verbose'] End of network processing
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.487Z] ['info'] Processing ./tests/_output/coverage.xml...
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.491Z] ['info'] Detected GitHub Actions as the CI provider.
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.491Z] ['verbose'] -> Using the following env variables:
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.491Z] ['verbose']      GITHUB_ACTION: __codecov_codecov-action
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.491Z] ['verbose']      GITHUB_HEAD_REF: 
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.491Z] ['verbose']      GITHUB_REF: refs/heads/development
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.491Z] ['verbose']      GITHUB_REPOSITORY: mepihindeveloper/php-data-entities
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.491Z] ['verbose']      GITHUB_RUN_ID: 1676757413
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.491Z] ['verbose']      GITHUB_SERVER_URL: https://github.com
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.491Z] ['verbose']      GITHUB_SHA: e43326f8f8bd41bcede524e6ec6ce32abfedb4e6
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.491Z] ['verbose']      GITHUB_WORKFLOW: build
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.491Z] ['verbose'] Using the following upload parameters:
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.491Z] ['verbose'] branch
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.492Z] ['verbose'] build
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.492Z] ['verbose'] buildURL
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.492Z] ['verbose'] commit
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.492Z] ['verbose'] job
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.492Z] ['verbose'] pr
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.492Z] ['verbose'] service
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.492Z] ['verbose'] slug
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.492Z] ['verbose'] name
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.493Z] ['verbose'] tag
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.493Z] ['verbose'] flags
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.493Z] ['verbose'] parent
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.494Z] ['info'] Pinging Codecov: https://codecov.io/upload/v4?package=github-action-2.1.0-uploader-0.1.13&token=*******&branch=development&build=1676757413&build_url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fmepihindeveloper%2Fphp-data-entities%2Factions%2Fruns%2F1676757413&commit=e43326f8f8bd41bcede524e6ec6ce32abfedb4e6&job=build&pr=&service=github-actions&slug=mepihindeveloper%2Fphp-data-entities&name=&tag=&flags=unittests&parent=
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.495Z] ['verbose'] Passed token was 36 characters long
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.495Z] ['verbose'] https://codecov.io/upload/v4?package=github-action-2.1.0-uploader-0.1.13&branch=development&build=1676757413&build_url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fmepihindeveloper%2Fphp-data-entities%2Factions%2Fruns%2F1676757413&commit=e43326f8f8bd41bcede524e6ec6ce32abfedb4e6&job=build&pr=&service=github-actions&slug=mepihindeveloper%2Fphp-data-entities&name=&tag=&flags=unittests&parent=
        Content-Type: 'text/plain'
        Content-Encoding: 'gzip'
        X-Reduced-Redundancy: 'false'
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.838Z] ['verbose'] Returned upload url: https://codecov.io/github/mepihindeveloper/php-data-entities/commit/e43326f8f8bd41bcede524e6ec6ce32abfedb4e6
https://storage.googleapis.com/codecov/v4/raw/2022-01-10/56A669BE10810EDE62C49B61543537BF/e43326f8f8bd41bcede524e6ec6ce32abfedb4e6/d0b8f565-00c5-4174-909e-d1dde0aa43ee.txt?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=GOOG1EKKHVKCKHW7KBCGM7IHR55T63V2PAVJWLVFNITJHDU5G6R5IRN3LMWJA%2F20220110%2FUS%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220110T095048Z&X-Amz-Expires=10&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=bb936b15534facce42220122a62da73347d9f5d0cd96dfc53bb201a8bbe1f5ef
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.838Z] ['verbose'] https://storage.googleapis.com/codecov/v4/raw/2022-01-10/56A669BE10810EDE62C49B61543537BF/e43326f8f8bd41bcede524e6ec6ce32abfedb4e6/d0b8f565-00c5-4174-909e-d1dde0aa43ee.txt?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=GOOG1EKKHVKCKHW7KBCGM7IHR55T63V2PAVJWLVFNITJHDU5G6R5IRN3LMWJA%2F20220110%2FUS%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220110T095048Z&X-Amz-Expires=10&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=bb936b15534facce42220122a62da73347d9f5d0cd96dfc53bb201a8bbe1f5ef
        Content-Type: 'text/plain'
        Content-Encoding: 'gzip'
[2022-01-10T09:50:48.838Z] ['info'] Uploading...
[2022-01-10T09:50:49.034Z] ['info'] {"status":"success","resultURL":"https://codecov.io/github/mepihindeveloper/php-data-entities/commit/e43326f8f8bd41bcede524e6ec6ce32abfedb4e6"}
[2022-01-10T09:50:49.034Z] ['verbose'] End of uploader: 586 milliseconds
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine. there was a wrong branch in the settings.